# Simply way to change an image source with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Yes I know there are threads asking this but the answers and examples are  over complicated.

From what I can find this should work but it just doesn't to either change the image when I reload the page or change on hover:

```
<body>
<img id='image'src='imagepathhere' height='200px' width='200px'>
<script>
document.getElementById('image').src='pathOfTheNewImage';
</script>
```

For a mouse over to change the image I think it is something like:

```
 <script>>   

function changeImage(image) {
    image.src = "pathOfNewImage";
}
</script>

<img id='image' src="pathOfOldImage" onmouseover="changeImage(this)" height='200px' width='200px'>
```

1) The source of both images are correct.

2) As again I see forms on here with the but the code is just so overly complicated I can't really follow it well.

Comment: `getElementById`, not `getElementByID`.

Comment: `onmouseover="document.getElementByID('image').src='pathOfNEwImage'"` doesn't do anything besides assign undefined to a local variable.

Comment: well that is not how you bind a mousover event...

Comment: Do some reading on how to create event listeners on elements. Also use your browser console to check errors and include them when asking questions

Comment: Is that first attempt failing in some way?  The second one certainly will because you're just assigning a string to a variable, not actually creating an event handler with actual code.

Comment: Assigning to `onmouseover` will attempt to assign to `window.onmouseover`, but it must be a function or `null`. If it’s not a function, it will be converted to `null`.

Comment: Thanks to your comments I managed to fix it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your code you are binding function incorrectly.  So basically you can bind function inline with html. Or you can bind it dynamically. This is very simple solution. If your image path is fixed.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function mouseaway(my_image) {
        my_image.src = "someimage.jpg";
    }

    function rollover(my_image) {
        my_image.src = "someimage.jpg";
    }
</script>

<img src="someimage.jpg" onmouseover="rollover(this)" onmouseout="mouseaway(this)" />
```

Comment: You should explain what exactly was wrong and what you did to fix it. Just dumping code here is not useful.

Comment: What is onmouseover in your code ? This not a right way to code it

Comment: FYI I am not the question asker.

Comment: Do you think what is mentioned in code is right? . So I just give a solution here.

Comment: But you are putting comments here. So you can compare the code before writing anything

Comment: I am not going to evaluate if the answer is correct or not - the OP and votes will do that. However, code with no explanation is not useful for this site so you should provide that explanation.

Comment: Actually thanks to your posted function I was able to figure it out. Thank you for keeping it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your posts I was able to get the function correct:

```
<img id='image'src='oldImage' onmouseover="changeImage(this)" 
height='200px' width='200px'>


<script>
function changeImage(image) {
image.src='newImage';
}
</script>
```